# Is ‘the’ correctly used in this context?

Tags: definite-article

In my essay I characterize the Polish problem of freedom, and discuss its characteristic features. That is, I want to suggest that there is a unique problem of freedom in Poland.

So when I say:

> It’s a good idea to consider **the** Polish problem of freedom in
> the broader context of European Union.

Is that ‘the’ necessary or I can omit it? I think that the adjective ‘Polish’ already defines ‘problem of freedom’ and so maybe that ‘the’ is not necessary or even wrongly used. Is that so?

Comment: Yes, "**the**" is necessary in this case.

Comment: Please don't write answers in comments.

Comment: @DJClayworth I didn't think that was an adequate answer on it's own and I don't possess sufficient technical knowledge of grammar to expand and explain it further.

Answer (score 1):

I gather that you have already defined or described a problem or issue that you are naming “Polish problem of freedom.” That issue differs from other problems that may affect Poland and differs from problems that may affect freedom in other states.

If that supposition is correct, then you should use the definite article to indicate that the phrase indicates a unique problem already defined. That is the purpose of the definite article.

Comment: So the adjective ‘Polish’ doesn’t already define it?

Comment: Absent a definition, “Polish problem of freedom” means nothing. Do Poles object to freedom? Do Poles object to freedom for minorities like Jews? Do Poles yearn for Russian or Prussian or Austrian domination? Do Poles have a concept of freedom different from that of Canadians or Finns? What is peculiar to Poles with regard to freedom, and why is it problematic? If you have defined what the phrase means, then English grammar requires a definite article to indicate that the phrase has previously been given a definite meaning. That is what definite articles are for.